# How to encrypt without a random number in Android

Tags: android, encryption, random

I currently have an accessory that uses AES/CBC without a random number on the key. Instead, the message itself includes a random number and the key is hard-coded. I'm trying to do the same thing on my Android to exchange with the accessory through BLE. Somehow I can't figure out how generate a Key-class object without using a random number.

Here's an example of what I'd like to be able to do:

```
 public byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] input) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding ");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        return cipher.doFinal(input);
    }
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] input) throws Exception {
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom(key);
    secureRandom.setSeed(key);
    keyGenerator.init(128, secureRandom);
    SecretKey secretkey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding ");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretkey);
    return cipher.doFinal(input);
}
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] input) throws Exception {
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES/CBC/NoPadding ");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding ");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
    return cipher.doFinal(input);
}
```

Unfortunately both of those alter the key before the encryption.

How can I use my key "as is"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to encrypt with your own key without salt or using any random, you can do as following.

```
    byte[] keyBuf= new byte[32];

    byte[] b= key.getBytes("UTF-8");
    int len= b.length;
    if (len > keyBuf.length) len = keyBuf.length;

    System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBuf, 0, len);
    SecretKey keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBuf, "AES");


    byte[] ivBuf= new byte[16];
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBuf);

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
```

Where `key` is my custom key as a String and b my key as a bytes[]. Initializing the cipher this way avoid the salting and allow you to always use your own key to encrypt anything.